# Animation of UI elements in modal view

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have view controller which invoke modal window when a button is pressed. The problem (for me) is that the UI elements in the modal window are animated while the modal view appear. Is this normal behavior ? Can I disable animation on UI elements on modal window ?

EDIT

```
....
ModalView *modalView = [[ModalView alloc]init];
[modalView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, if you dont want the animation while the modal View appears make the following change -

`[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:NO];`

See what I changed? Make `animated:NO`.

Comment: When animated is set to NO the modal view is not appear.

Comment: if you need to animation then `[modalView setModalTransitionStyle:nil];`. What was happening was since you kept the `transitionStyle` as `partialCurl` & then the animation as `NO` it was creating a problem. Now try...